# Node js website shuts down when I shutdown my pc (Hostinger)

Tags: node.js, express, web, hosting, vps

Okay, so I made a website for an education institute using html css javascript and used node and express for backend path stuff like /courses or /admission . Now when I hosted my website on Hostinger using shared hosting, I figured since there is no node js installed by default my website navbar wasn't working whenever I clicked on a page it just gave an error.

So I got premium web hosting from "Hostinger" with SSH access and then followed the steps in the article I found on Medium "How to host a node.js app on shared host". And it worked like a charm, I used "forever" to make my app run even when I quit the terminal. But now whenever I close my computer, the website doesn't work. which defeats the whole purpose of hosting.

Am I doing something wrong? I contacted support and they said I should use VPS because their shared hosting doesn't support node js, even after I installed it. But before spending any more money I just need someone to help me out and clear my confusion. Is it how everyone does I mean VPS seems complicated but then how do people use shared hosting and have their navbar and other pages linked perfectly? Or should I ditch node js and use something else to link pages that is supported on shared hosting as well? I have no problem going, either way, I just don't want to hit a dead end because I am on a tight deadline.

I tried to follow these steps in this article to make my hosting plan run node js. https://medium.com/@mayomi1/how-to-host-a-node-js-app-on-shared-host-52e12a62a259

Comment: Not sure if it will work but worth trying: instead of `forever start app.js` try to run `npm start &` which will run the server on the background and should not depend on the ssh connection.

Comment: Why even bother with managing an OS or (unsupported) runtime etc. when you don't have any experience with it or don't want to bother with maintaining it. Why not use [PaaS (Platform as a Service)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) offerings from cloud providers e.g. Google App Engine, Azure App Service or AWS Elastic Beanstalk which manage the OS and runtime for you and you just need to care about your app (and which do support Node.js). I believe that would be a much better option for you and probably an even more cost effective/ free solution.